# Prototype Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

According to wikipedia prototype pattern is : 
The prototype pattern is a creational design pattern used in software development when the type of objects to create is determined by a prototypical instance, which is cloned to produce new objects. This pattern is used to:

1. Avoid subclasses of an object creator in the client application, like the abstract factory pattern does.
2. Avoid the inherent cost of creating a new object in the standard way (e.g., using the `new` keyword) when it is prohibitively expensive for a given application.

---

I saw certain demo codes of this pattern in C++ all of them are using copy constructor.
Can anyone explain how point number two applies(in general as well as in context of C++) as we are using copy constructor anyways in clone function. If it can be done without copy constructor then an example code snippet would be great.

Comment: Cloning by definition involves copying, so the only way to not involve either the copy-constructor or assignment-operator would be to have a special function that copies all fields manually. Although this might invoke the copy-constructors of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy without dynamic allocation. For example, here's a cloning that only happens in a local scope:

```
Foo prototype;

void local()
{
    Foo x = prototype; // first copy
    x.mutate();
    Foo y = x;         // another copy
}
```

No dynamic allocation is used, ever.

It is true that `return new Foo(*this);` *also* makes a copy, but what's more important is that *that* object is allocated dynamically. *That*'s the cost that your article to which is alluding.

Answer (score 1):

In a game I've been making in Java, I ran into an interesting situation that fit the bill of a prototype pattern quite well. You see, I had this Animation object that stored a container of images to flip through, as well as some other data that tracked how long since the last frame was rendered, which frame it was on, if the animation was running or not, etc.

I found that for multiple characters to use the same Animation object was causing problems. If two characters shared an animation, they would turn on and turn off the animation at conflicting times for each other. I would have guys standing still with walking animations, or moving with standing animations. Creation of the animation objects were costly and time consuming what with creating the sprites, setting the ammount of time they would display for, creating an interval queue of images, etc.

Instead, I made the Animation object a prototype object. If an Animation clones itself, It shares the original collection of frames with all other animations since those are immutable, but also expensive to construct. Instead the new objects would share this immutable base, but have their own information of which frame to draw and when.

Think of it like a projector. When it get's cloned, the new projector might have it's own information on if it's running or not, which frame it's on, etc, but it may be using the same piece of film that the original projector is using. The reason why they don't trip each other up is that the film is immutable. (and expensive to create)

In all honesty, the usage of the prototype in this manner is a great way to implement a flyweight pattern. Objects that share Objects that are expensive to create. If you "clone" them, they would be instantiated with their new transient state, but still share those expensive base objects with it's creator.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the copy constructor for object which isn't use dynamic memory inside itself is much more faster then perform any allocation in dynamic memory via `new`. Because allocation in dynamic memory is a kind of system call.